# Check all lines in a huge CSV file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, optimization, reader

I want to work with a CSV file of more than 300,000 lines. I need to verify information line by line and then display it in a .txt file in the form of a table to see which file was missing for all servers. For example

```
Name,Server
File1,Server1
File2,Server1
File3,Server1
File1,Server2
File2,Server2
...
File345,Server76
File346,Server32
```

I want to display in table form this result which corresponds to the example above:

```
Name     Server1 Server2 ... Server 32 ....Server 76
File1       X       X
File2       X       X
File3       X       
...
File345                                       X
File346                          X
```

To do this actually, I have a function that creates objects where the members are the Server Name (The number of members object can change) and I use stream reader to split data (I have more than 2 columns in my csv so 0 is for the Server name and 5 for the file name)

```
$stream = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($File)
$stream.ReadLine()  | Out-Null
while ((-not $stream.EndOfStream)) {
    $line = $stream.ReadLine()
    $strTempo = $null
    $strTempo = $line -split ","
    $index = $listOfFile.Name.IndexOf($strTempo[5])
    if ($index -ne -1) {   
        $property = $strTempo[0].Replace("-", "_")
        $listOfFile[$index].$property = "X"
    }
    else {
        $obj = CreateEmptyObject ($listOfConfiguration)
        $obj.Name = $strTempo[5]
        $listOfFile.Add($obj) | Out-Null
    }
}
```

When I export this I have a pretty good result. But the script take so much time (between 20min to 1hour)

I didn't know how optimize actually the script. I'm beginner to PowerShell.

Thanks for the futures tips

Comment: Please provide a working [mcve]. (`$strTempo[5]` is far outside the given number of columns). It might also be nice to provide a way to create a sample csv file, e.g.: `1..1000 |ForEach-Object -Begin { 'Name,Server' } -Process { "File$(Random 100),Server$(Random 100)" } |Set-Content .\List.csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1)s for this:

```
$Servers = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::New()
$Files = @{}
Import-Csv -Path $Path |ForEach-Object {
    $Null = $Servers.Add($_.Server)
    if ($Files.Contains($_.Name)) { $Null = $Files[$_.Name].Add($_.Server) }
    else { $Files[$_.Name] = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]$_.Server }
}
$Table = foreach($Name in $Files.get_Keys()) {
    $Properties = [Ordered]@{ Name = $Name }
    ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {
        $Properties[$Server] = if ($Files[$Name].Contains($Server)) { 'X' }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$Properties
}
$Table |Format-Table -Property @{ expression='*' }
```

Note that in contrast to PowerShell's usual behavior, the .Net `HashSet` class is **case-sensitive** by default. To create an **case-insensitive** `HashSet` use the following constructor:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::New([StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply. I have tried this in another script. He actually take 2-3 minutes now. (He take 1hour before) 
Thank's so much.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works faster.  Change filename as required

```
$Path = "C:\temp\test1.txt"
$table = Import-Csv -Path $Path
$columnNames = $table | Select-Object -Property Server -Unique| foreach{$_.Server} | Sort-Object
Write-Host "names = " $columnNames
$groups = $table | Group-Object {$_.Name}

$outputTable =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach($group in $groups)
{
   Write-Host "Group = " $group.Name
   $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
   $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue $group.Name
   $servers = $group.Group | Select-Object -Property Server | foreach{$_.Server}
Write-Host "servers = " $servers
   foreach($item in $columnNames)
   {
      if($servers.Contains($item))
      {
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $item -NotePropertyValue 'X'
      }
      else
      {
         #if you comment out next line code doesn't work
         $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $item -NotePropertyValue ''
      }
   }
   $outputTable.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
   
}
$outputTable | Format-Table
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply, that work pretty good ! My script take actually 6 minutes. I didn't know how use Group-Object. I think i gonna use this command more